# How to destroy an angular factory instance

Tags: angularjs, websocket, factory

On the one hand, I have several factories where each factory controls a websocket.

On the other hand, One of those factories should be started when client is logged, so:

```
if(user.isLogged()){
 $injector.get('NotificationsWebsocket')
}
```

That's the way I initialize my factory dinamically, the problem come up when the user logs out.

I don't know how to delete an instance of angular instances factory or how to destroy the NotificationsWebsocket.
I tried to close socket, but when I log in again, the socket doesn't connect because factory is not reinstanciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot destroy factories, they are singletons and they are created only once when they are first required by a module.

You can add to your factory two methods: `setup()`, `close()` which will create and close socket.

When user logins you call `setup()`, when logging out - `close()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: By the way...then all providers are singleton, am I right?

Comment: Correct. _Note: All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs._ Taken from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Comment: Factories return an object they are not singletons services however are singletons

Comment: @MichaelWarner documentation may be a bit confusing but both `Services` and `Factories` are indeed singletons.

Comment: @ieaglle I tested it out and it seems they both a singletons. Here is the results of my test.
https://plnkr.co/edit/E9epFzX7KP9lyZT4I6YT?p=preview