# Can I reload app without refreshing view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router in my application, and I am wondering if I can reload - or destroy services when user is logging out, without refreshing the view? So far, when user is logging out, backend logs him out, and he is redirected to the login view. However, all of the services are still working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990480/how-to-destroy-an-angularjs-app

Comment: Isn't the user also logged out from service on server-side? it should be the case? ideally giving HTTP 401 with an json result

Answer (score 0):

UI Router provides with state transition events, so you can listen for the transition event, and when the transition happens to the login page, you can manually refresh your services. By refresh I mean you can bring them to initial state by initializing them to initial state.

You can keep a function like `close()` in your service which declares everything again. So you can call this function on logout to refresh your service.

refer this for example: [Refresh factory/service instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781488/how-to-destroy-an-angular-factory-instance)

Comment: How can I bring a state to initial state?

Comment: Lets say your service has a variable `abc` which might be initially defined as `var abc = []`. so in the event handler, you can again declare it as empty array. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Controller where the logout button is called
.controller("ctrl", function(destroyService){

   this.logout = function(){
      //Probably an ajax request to logout from server.
      $http.post("logoutUrl", userId)
         .then(function(){
            destroyService.destroyAll();
            $state.go("loginPage");
         });
   };

})


.service("destroyService", ["service1", "service2", function(service1, service2){

  this.destroyAll = function(){
    service1.destroyAll();
    service2.destroyAll();
  };

}]);
```